What are the criteria for assessing network congestion in the metrics of the Solana cluster state?
How can I know whether solana network is in congestion or not, using solanabeach.io or explorer.solana.com ?
Current TPS? or Average Ping Time?

It's a very hard metric to suss out, since "congestion" usually means two different things:

There's "congestion" from transactions spamming the network, which can make it hard for an unstaked client to get a transaction to a leader. This type of congestion is mitigated by stake-weighted quality-of-service (swqos) though.
There's "congestion" of too many valid transactions vying for block space. This type of congestion is typically mitigated by setting appropriate priority fees.

So the better metric might be the percent of transactions that get confirmed, which you can see by mousing over the "Average Ping Time" bars in explorer.solana.com. If transactions aren't landing, it might show that the Ping tool isn't setting high enough priority fees, or that there's too much spam congesting the network.
